# Sinon stub axios throws error : TypeError: Attempted to wrap get which is already wrapped

Tags: axios, sinon, stubbing

There are few existing questions on stack overflow with this error but none of them explains this error on stubbing `axios`. I took the boilerplate working example from sinonjs.org and tried to mock `axios`. It throws the error

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap get which is already wrapped

Code below:

```js
import Axios from 'axios';

var sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();

describe('axios.get method', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    // stub out the `axios` method
    sandbox.stub(Axios, 'get');
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    // completely restore all fakes created through the sandbox
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should be called once', function () {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got this error is that you stub the `Axios.get` method more than once. The code you provided works fine. So you need to call `sanbox.restore()` method to restore all fakes created through the sandbox before stubbing the method again. Please check your code DOES NOT stub the `Axios.get` method continuous.

E.g.

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import Axios from 'axios';
import sinon from 'sinon';
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('axios.get method', () => {
  let axiosGetStub;
  beforeEach(() => {
    axiosGetStub = sandbox.stub(Axios, 'get');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should be called once', () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3000');
    sandbox.assert.calledOnce(axiosGetStub);
  });
  it('should be called once again', () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3000');
    sandbox.assert.calledOnce(axiosGetStub);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
  axios.get method
    ✓ should be called once
    ✓ should be called once again


  2 passing (29ms)
```